# Top of UITableView is Cut Off

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uistoryboard

The top of my UITableView that I embedded into my view controller is cut off

[image: cut off.]

I can only see it when scrolling makes the view bounce. The container containing the UITableView is part of a vertical stack view that has these constraints

[image: constraints.]

Comment: You seem to be missing a bottom / height constraint.

Comment: @gkpln3 It worked! I had to add a Bottom constraint to the safe area, and remove the constraint that aligned the view to center y. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can set `contentInset` of tableView from `top` side like below code :

**Code:**

```
yourTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

it's work for me i hope it will work for you.

Thanks.